# Prometheus instance label vs containers

Tags: prometheus

In a continuous delivery scenario, where services are running in containers and being deployed multiple times per day, what is the correct value to use as the `instance` label?

Using the container id seems natural, but this will result in a high number of historical values for `instance` over time (even though only a relatively small set of values for will be "active" at any point in time).

Will this start to cause a performance problem in Prometheus, given the advice that the cardinality of any label should not be unbounded.

If so, can it be mitigated in any way, for example by adjusting retention periods or using a different storage engine such as the influx DB adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've researched this some more, and found this video by one of the maintainers, Fabian Reinartz, extremely enlightening:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nDalewt4BOw

Basically, it's not a problem for Prometheus 2.0 upwards to just use container id as the `instance` label.

In Prometheus 2, it has a new time series db which is optimised for this case. Also, when Prometheus 2 detects an `instance` has been down for too long it assumes it has been killed and won't be coming back, and so formally closes that instance's time series. This prevents the ever growing set of time series and helps solve the problem.

I guess theoretically this would also mean we can ignore retired historical values for labels when calculating cardinality, as values which are no longer in use will eventually have all their associated time series closed by this mechanism (assuming an instance cycling situation, like the one I described) - but it would be great to get clarification in the docs on this.